# launching Python from notepad ++ specify location and size of window

Tags: python, notepad++, python-idle

I'm running python code from notepad ++ with a shortcut

`” C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat -r "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

when it runs it pops up in the middle for the screen.

How do I specify where it should pop up? I want to put it in the top right corner of the screen.

I would also like to be able to specify how big the size of the python shell should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For initial shell and editor size, open Options => Configure IDLE => General tab.  Find `Initial Window Size` and set the height and width in lines and characters.

There is no setting for initial position, as it would be a bad idea to have all windows open in exactly the same position.  Better to let the OS cascade them.

On the other hand, initial position of the first window would be useful.  For your use, a command line option, say `-x pixels_from left, -y pixels from top`, would work.  But most people either use the IDLE editor for .py files or link the python shell to other editors, and do not explicitly use a command line.  So I will consider adding `Initial Position of First Window` to the config dialog.